# change code from C# windows form to class

Tags: c#, function, class

Hi i have this one windows form but i need to modify the code so that it runs as a class not a form. The InvokeRequired  and Invoke functions are stopping me from doing this. I have updated the code to show the complete class. The code constantly updates to check if a whole list of values have changed

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ets2SdkClient.Demo
{
public partial class Ets2SdkClientDemo : Form
{
    public Ets2SdkTelemetry Telemetry;

    public Ets2SdkClientDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Telemetry = new Ets2SdkTelemetry();
        Telemetry.Data += Telemetry_Data;

        Telemetry.JobFinished += TelemetryOnJobFinished;
        Telemetry.JobStarted += TelemetryOnJobStarted;


    }

    private void TelemetryOnJobFinished(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Job finished, or at least unloaded nearby cargo destination.");
    }

    private void TelemetryOnJobStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Just started job OR loaded game with active.");
    }

    private void Telemetry_Data(Ets2Telemetry data, bool updated)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new TelemetryData(Telemetry_Data), new object[2] { data, updated });
                return;
            }


            // Do some magic trickery to display ALL info:
            var grps = new object[]
                   {
                       data.Drivetrain, data.Physics, data.Controls, data.Axilliary, data.Damage, data.Lights, data.Job
                   };

            foreach (var grp in grps)
            {
                // Find the right tab page:
                var grpName = grp.GetType().Name;
                if (grpName.StartsWith("_"))
                    grpName = grpName.Substring(1);



                // All properties;
                var props = grp.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                var labels = new StringBuilder();
                var vals = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    labels.AppendLine(prop.Name + ":");
                    object val = prop.GetValue(grp, null);
                    if (val is float[])
                    {
                        vals.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", (val as float[]).Select(x=> x.ToString("0.000"))));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vals.AppendLine(val.ToString());
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you better if you provide a [mcve]. This means that you should give enough code that anyone can copy/paste it and run it without any errors.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help, removing it and leaving the invoke call would be infinite recursion and it doesn't really do anything other than call itself on the UI thread. I'm sure there is more to this method, you should be able to remove those lines entirely

Comment: @RonBeyer Infinite recursion how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382735/generic-begininvoke-scheme-to-ensure-function-calls-in-same-threading-context/24389573#24389573

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If you did a conversion of that line, which just calls itself via a delegate, it would just continually call itself. Which is why I said id doesn't really do anything (other than invoke on the UI thread) and can be removed entirely, no "conversion" needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that. You can remove the entire "if" block, because all what Invoke() does here is make sure that the method executes on the same thread as the window runs on. This is no longer required if you do not have a window. However, you might need to understand thread concurrency (if your application uses multiple threads) and potentially you have to include locks to prevent such problems.

Comment: I wonder how you know that the application does not already use multiple threads..? I highly doubt a person without a lot of experience would randomly add Invoke calls (I'd much likely think they copied it when they got a multithreading issue...).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Yea, I agree on that one, but on the other hand, this is such a basic question that I fear the complete answer would be to difficult here. (Besides that there's not enough information given to help with that).